# Alternatives to drawing with Swing components

Tags: swing, opengl, drawing, lines

We're making a program that are required to draw about 200000 lines of different kinds.
At the moment we are using Swing to draw on a component, but it really isn't fast enough.

The question: Are there any faster way to draw lines, than the Swing library. Is AWT faster, is OpenGL the way to roll (and is it faster) and so on.

Comment: What kind of lines are you drawing? (Just tested drawing 200000 lines in less then 50 ms...)

Comment: Can you post a very short self-contained code example showing what you are doing? This will help find the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information you provide the only thing i can recommend you is to try to use the class :

> javafx.scene.shape.Line;

I think you are probably ussing.

> java.awt.geom.Line2D;

awt components used to be in applets and they are heavyweight if you use them, that might be a reason of your performance issues.

Have a look at JavaFX ( www.javafx.com )  maybe you find some component that suits your needs(faster).

Here an example how to draw a line in Java using Graphics2D: http://www.javadb.com/drawing-a-line-using-java-2d-graphics-api